# Esiste la parola mentuladossia?

Tags: word-meaning, neologism

La lessi una volta e mi dissero che fosse un opinione di scarsa rilevanza basata su un analisi cinofallica ma ostentata con vigore, tuttavia, cercando su vari dizionari non l'ho mai trovata. Ma esiste realmente?

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!!

Comment: Il riferimento proviene da [Il calidrino](http://www.ilcalidrino.it/)

Comment: **mentuladossìa** s.f.. Opinione di scarsa rilevanza derivante da un'analisi dei fatti sommaria ma condotta e strenuamente movimentata con il rigore volgarmente tipico del membro maschile. [Comp. di lat. mentula «fallo» e –dossia, dal gr. dóxa «opinione»].

Comment: Il Calidrino è un piccolo dizionario anomalo di neologismi creati per descrivere cose che esistono ma non hanno un nome e cose che hanno un nome ma non esistono.

Qui viene descritto che cosa è il Calidrino: Come in un normale dizionario, ogni voce del Calidrino è definita nel suo significato fondamentale, è corredata da una breve spiegazione etimologica e seguita, laddove richiesto, da immagini, approfondimenti, commenti o esempi d’uso.

Comment: Su Treccani non è presente nella [lista dei neologismi](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/neologismi/searchNeologismi.jsp?cercaTesto=mentuladossia&searchIn=V&cercaTestoVis=) quindi direi di no, almeno ufficialmente.

Comment: @abarisone: Il problema è: cosa significa affermare che una parola "esiste"? Se si usa nel sito web che hai citato, io direi che esiste (nel senso che è stata creata dalla mente di qualcuno). Se poi è usata o meno da altre persone, è un'altra cosa.

Comment: @Charo Giusta osservazione. Usando come parametro Treccani e volendo essere pignoli si può dire che non esiste ufficialmente in nessun dizionario. Poi è chiaro che la lingua è viva ed evolve (pensa al famoso caso di [petaloso](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/neologismi/searchNeologismi.jsp?lettera=P&pathFile=/sites/default/BancaDati/Osservatorio_della_Lingua_Italiana/Marzo_2016/petaloso.xml&lettera=P) che si è fatto strada nel vocabolario) e quindi nuove parole entrano mentre altre escono...

Comment: Nel caso di petaloso non bastava che la parola fosse stata, passami il termine, inventata ma, secondo gli studiosi dell'Accademia della Crusca, era necessario che venisse usata in vari contesti.

Comment: Per curiosità, @Michele, come mai ti poni il dubbio per “mentuladossia” mentre usi tranquillamente “cinofallico”, che appartiene allo stesso tipo di coniazioni scherzose e pseudodotte, tutte figlie del gaddiano “cinobalanico”?

Answer (score 4):

Il riferimento proviene proviene da [Il calidrino](http://www.ilcalidrino.it/).

***mentuladossìa*** s.f.. Opinione di scarsa rilevanza derivante da un'analisi dei fatti sommaria ma condotta e strenuamente movimentata con il rigore volgarmente tipico del membro maschile. 
[Comp. di lat. mentula «fallo» e –dossia, dal gr. dóxa «opinione»].

> Il Calidrino è un piccolo dizionario anomalo di neologismi creati per
>   descrivere cose che esistono ma non hanno un nome e cose che hanno un
>   nome ma non esistono.
>
> Come in un normale dizionario, ogni voce del Calidrino è definita nel
>   suo significato fondamentale, è corredata da una breve spiegazione
>   etimologica e seguita, laddove richiesto, da immagini,
>   approfondimenti, commenti o esempi d’uso

Su Treccani non è presente nella [lista dei neologismi](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/neologismi/searchNeologismi.jsp?cercaTesto=mentuladossia&searchIn=V&cercaTestoVis=) quindi direi di no, almeno ufficialmente.

Considerando la giusta osservazione di @Charo riguardante i criteri per stabilire se una parola esiste (e viene quindi riportata dai vocabolari) oppure no, riporto di seguito la risposta dell'Accademia della Crusca nel caso della famosa parola [petaloso](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/laccademia/notizie-dallaccademia/parola-petaloso-possibilit-entrare-vocabolari):

> La tua parola è bella e chiara, ma sai come fa una parola a entrare
>   nel vocabolario? Una parola nuova non entra nel vocabolario quando
>   qualcuno la inventa, anche se è una parola “bella” e utile. Perché
>   entri in un vocabolario, infatti, bisogna che la parola nuova non sia
>   conosciuta e usata solo da chi l’ha inventata, ma che la usino tante
>   persone e che tante persone la capiscano. Se riuscirai a diffondere la
>   tua parola fra tante persone e tante persone in Italia cominceranno a
>   dire e a scrivere “Com’è petaloso questo fiore!” o, come suggerisci
>   tu, “le margherite sono fiori petalosi, mentre i papaveri non sono
>   molto petalosi”, ecco, allora petaloso sarà diventata una parola
>   dell’italiano, perché gli italiani la conoscono e la usano. A quel
>   punto chi compila i dizionari inserirà la nuova parola fra le altre e
>   ne spiegherà il significato. È così che funziona: non sono gli
>   studiosi, quelli che fanno i vocabolari, a decidere quali parole nuove
>   sono belle o brutte, utili o inutili. Quando una parola nuova è sulla
>   bocca di tutti (o di tanti), allora lo studioso capisce che quella
>   parola è diventata una parola come le altre e la mette nel
>   vocabolario.

Comment: Che cos'è il Calidrino? Cioè, è un testo classico, è un blog di qualcuno...?

Comment: Sembra sia un blog di neologismi semiseri, dove si può anche acquistare una sorta di vocabolario cartaceo.

Comment: Occorrerebbe però aggiungere che la parola è morfologicamente difettosa. Si tratta di un composto ibrido latino-greco (il composto solo greco sarebbe _fallodossía_, cfr. _fallocrazia_); ma quando il secondo elemento è greco, il primo, che funge da prefissoide, subisce la cancellazione della vocale finale, che viene poi sostituita da _-o-_ (nei composti con secondo elemento latino, invece, la vocale sostitutiva è _-i-_, es. _divertimentificio_). Pertanto, la forma corretta è _mentulodossia_.